# Error when creating a Spark session in Zeppelin Docker: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with Scala and Java

Tags: java, docker, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

****Hello, StackOverflow community!****

I am facing a problem when trying to run Apache Spark in Zeppelin using Docker. When creating a SparkSession in PySpark, the following error occurs:

org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Settings.usejavacp()Lscala/tools/nsc/settings/AbsSettings$AbsSetting

*Here is the configuration of my environment:*

- Spark versions 3.5.0
- Java OpenJDK versions 17.0.7
- Scala versions 2.12.18
- Python versions 3.9.0

*I am using the following code to create a SparkSession in PySpark:*

```
%pyspark
from pyspark import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .master("local[*]")
         .appName('PySpark_Tutorial')
         .getOrCreate())
```

*I use the Docker command to run Zeppelin:*

docker run -u $(id -u) -p 8080:8080 -p 4040:4040 --rm -v /mnt/c/spark:/opt/spark -e SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.11.0

The `HOME` paths and `PATH` variables are set correctly. I have not tried using older versions of Spark or Scala. There is speculation that the problem may be due to incompatibility between Scala and Spark versions.

I tried running Apache Spark in Zeppelin via Docker using the specified versions of Java, Scala and Python. I expected a Spark session to be successfully created with no errors. Instead encountered a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` error, apparently related to Scala settings. I have checked that all environment variables (`HOME` and `PATH`) are set correctly and match the required paths. Also verified that compatible versions of all components are used. I expected the configuration to work without problems, but encountered this error.

Comment: I am running in this issue as well and can't figure it out. Scala 2.12 and Spark 3.5 are compatible according to Spark documentation. I see you are using zeppelin:0.11.0, but if you looked into hub.docker.com Zeppelin repo and it's image layers, you would that this Zeppelin image uses version 0.10.0 version. You could try to write your own Dockerfile and change Z_VERSION to 0.11.0. I have done this on my end, but it doesn't work...